# limit text files to a certain word length, but keep complete sentences

Tags: bash, machine-learning, nlp, feature-selection, normalize

I have a corpus of text files that I need to copy, but limiting each file to roughly the same word length, while maintaining complete sentences. Treating any punctuation within `{.?!}` as a sentence boundary is acceptable. I could do this with python, but I am trying to learn bash, so suggestions are welcome. The approach I have been considering is to overshoot my target word length by a few words and then trim the result to the last sentence boundary.

I am familiar with `head` and `wc`, but I can't come up with a way to combine the two. The `man` file for `head` does not indicate a way to use word-counts, and the `man` file for `wc` does not indicate a way to split the file.

Context:
I am working on a text classification task with machine-learning (using `weka`, for the record). I want to make sure that text length (which varies widely in my data) is not influencing the outcomes too much. To do this, I am trying to normalize my text lengths before I perform feature extraction.

Comment: I don't know about bash, but this doesn't sound like a very good idea to me, because you might lose important information this way. I would start by using TF-IDF for feature extraction and then a chi square test to keep fewer features (only the important ones). This will ensure that the important features are kept for each text, regardless of length. Have you had problems with this? There are better methods, but I'm not aware of anything that drops entire words from the original text.

Comment: @IVlad The classification task is based on text complexity (ie readability), so shortening the text assumes that all parts of the text are of roughly the same complexity. Losing particular terms isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
Do I exist? I program. Therefore, I am!
```

Suppose that we want to truncate this file to complete sentences of 20 characters or fewer:

```
$ awk -v n=20 -v RS='[.?!]' '{if (length(s $0 RT)>n) exit; else s=s $0 RT;} END{print s;}' file
Do I exist?
```

If we want 30 characters or fewer:

```
$ awk -v n=30 -v RS='[.?!]' '{if (length(s $0 RT)>n) exit; else s=s $0 RT;} END{print s;}' file
Do I exist? I program.
```

#### How it works

- `-v n=20`

  This sets the awk variable `n` to the max length that we want (not counting the file's final newline character).
- `-v RS='[.?!]'`

  This sets the awk record separator, `RS`, to any of the three characters that you mentioned.
- `if (length(s $0 RT)>n) exit; else s=s $0 RT`

  For each record in the file (a record being a sentence), we test to see if adding it to `s` would make the output too long.  If it makes the output too long, then we exit.  If not, we add it to `s`.

  In awk, `$0` represents the complete record and `RT` is the record separator that awk found at the end of the record.
- `END{print s;}`

  Before we exit, this prints the string `s`.

#### Alternate 1: Truncating based on number of words

Suppose instead that we want to truncate based on the number of words.  If we want, for example, 6 words:

```
$ awk -v n=6 -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'NR>n{exit;} {printf "%s%s",$0,RT;} END{print"";}' file
Do I exist? I program. Therefore,
```

The difference is that we know used whitespace as a record separator.  In this way, each record is a word and keep printing words until we reach the limit.

#### Alternative 2:  Whole sentences but limited number of words

```
$ awk -v n=6 -v RS='[.?!]' '{c+=NF; if (c>n) exit; else s=s $0 RT;} END{print s;}' file
Do I exist? I program.
```

#### Mac OSX

The above sets the record separator, `RS`, to a regular expression.  This may require GNU awk (gawk).  The [OSX man page for `awk`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/awk.1.html) does not say whether this feature is supported or not.  @bebop, however, reports that the above code can be run successfully on OSX after installing `gawk` from macports.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer! I have never used `awk`, but I am willing to try it out. Is there a simple way to do this based on word-count, rather than character-count? Tokenization doesn't have to be perfect. Just splitting on whitespace is sufficient.

Comment: awk is the right tool for this job.  I added an example that truncates based not on sentences or characters but on word count.

Comment: Yes, but this does not yield a complete sentence. I want to specify an approximate word count, but then ensure that I cut at a nearby sentence boundary.

Comment: OK.  I added a version for that.

Comment: Thanks again! You have convinced me that I need to take some time to learn `awk`. It seems to be very well-suited to this kind of text processing job.

Comment: For future readers, the version of `awk` that comes with OS X (version 20070501) does not work with this code. I installed `gawk` from macports, and it works.

Comment: @bebop Hmm.   Sorry for the inconvenience.  My guess is that the BSD version of awk does not support the use of a regex for `RS`.  I added your information on OSX to the answer.